# How Ansible Script module return execution result for every command in the script?

Tags: ansible

I execute a shell script in remote hosts using ansible script module. My shell script **test.sh** is

```
pwd
echo "hello"
ls -l
```

My ansible playbook is

```
- name: Transfer and execute a script.
  hosts: server
  tasks:
     - name: Copy and Execute the script 
       script: /root/test.sh
```

Besides, I want to view the execution result of every command in the script. But i only watched result.

```
changed: [172.18.96.134]
changed: [172.18.96.244]
changed: [172.18.96.245]
```

How can i watch result like this:

```
/root
hello
a.txt  test.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. It's not possible to trace a module on-line in Ansible. You can write your own log from the script.

Ansible standard way to handle such requirements is [Asynchronous Actions and Polling](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_async.html#asynchronous-actions-and-polling) to efficiently handle the output of the potentially large number of hosts.

It's possible to [register](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables) and print the module's result.

```yaml
    - name: Copy and Execute the script 
      script: /root/test.sh
      register: result
    - debug:
        var: result.stdout
```