# Print real time script output running on remote in ansible

Tags: ansible, output

I am running a bash script from the playbook. The bash script runs multiple scripts in parallel in-turn on a remote machine and it will give the output on console only when the entire playbook is executed. I want to print the output real-time. Is it possible?

Storing of result with 'register' provided by ansible to print output is not helping here. As I need real-time output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Ansible Script module return execution result for every command in the script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57407302/how-ansible-script-module-return-execution-result-for-every-command-in-the-scrip)

Comment: No. That is not what am looking for. I have mentioned above that I tried register but its not helping me to get real-time result on console

Comment: Your question: "Is it possible to print in real-time the output of scripts running from a playbook?" The answer is: No. For details see the link.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to take influence on a script "realtime" that is currently running.

U could use the failed_when to catch script errors:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#controlling-what-defines-failure

or u catch errors in the script self at runtime.